# can I run a split ms access database on a linux server?

Tags: linux, microsoft-access

An ms access database has been split so that the back end of it is on a windows server, while the front end GUI is on each user's windows PC. Is it possible for the back end to run on a Linux server instead of a windows server?  The clients would of course remain windows.

I am wondering if some third party may have developed an add on to make this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access databases (*.mdb, *.accdb) are just files. There is no Database sever running on the server for MS-Access; it serves only as file server. Therefore it should be possible.

No Access specific add on is required.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support this?

Comment: Look for a documentation on how to etablish a network connection between Windows and Linux. All you need, is to be able to access files on the Linux server from a Windows PC.